# About mvn dependency:analyze Unused declared dependencies found problem

Tags: maven

I run `mvn dependency:analyze` command to check the unused jar in my java project, part of the result as bellow:

> [WARNING] **Unused declared dependencies found**: [WARNING]
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:comp
>   ile [WARNING]
>   org.springframework.boot:**spring-boot-starter-test**:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE
>   :compile [WARNING]
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE
>   :compile [WARNING]
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.0.3.REL
>   EASE:compile [WARNING]    org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.9:compile
>   [WARNING]

But `spring-boot-starter-test` is actually used in src/test/java package,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
public class TestClass {
...
}
```

I want to know why **spring-boot-starter-test:** appear in **Unused declared dependencies found** section. 
Is there a way to find the exact jar which is not used in my java project

Answer (score 0):

If you declared the dependency without a `<scope>` tag, `<scope>compile</scope>` will be used.
If you use it for testing only, you should declare it as `<scope>test</scope>`.

Comment: Hi dan1st:I've tried <scope>compile</scope> or <scope>test</scope>, and it still appear in  Unused declared dependencies found, and beside unit-test class, some other jars such as spring-boot-starter-jdbc also has this problem

Comment: Part of Text fragment is paste as bellow   : <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: What happens if you delete the dependency?

Comment: There are references in the code，and eclipse show compile errors

Comment: Are the references only in src/main/java (or the testing directory)?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-jdbc are used in  src/main/java and spring-boot-starter-test are used in spring-boot-starter-test.

Comment: If this is so, `spring-boot-starter-test` should be declared as `<scope>test</scope>`

Comment: Hi dan1st, If I change the scope to test, and the whole spring boot jar will not be involved, and The project start will fail. I am  wonder if I can use mvn dependency:analyze  to check the jar which is not used in java project ,why is used jar appears in Unused declared dependencies found section? Is there something I missed?

Comment: Is your `spring-boot-starter-test` directory included in your spring boot jar?

Comment: spring-boot-starter-test  and spring-boot-starter-jdbc is a dependency in pom.xml. And The spring boot jars is included when I used these dependency

Comment: I mean the following:
Is the code that references your test dependency in src/main/java or in a test folder(normally src/main/java)?

Comment: The source is in src/test/java,and after mvn dependency:analyze  ,the class is in target/test-classes

Comment: I think it should solve the problem if you change it to src/test/java. Test-classes should be in the test source directory.

Comment: Dan1st, I've tried, but it didn't slove the problem.

Comment: Did you try it in combination with `<scope>test</scope>`?

Comment: I tried scope with test and Test-classes should be in the test source directory, the problem still exist

Comment: Is the code, that uses these dependencies test code or actual production code?
If it is only test code, you should be able to move the whole test code into `src/main/test` and set the scope of these dependencies to `test`.

Comment: Yes, I just use these  for test code and these code is already in src/main/test, and also I try set scope to test. And the problem is exist . The problem is now not only spring-boot-starter-test but also some other spring-boot-starter has the problem. I am suspect that it has something related to spring-boot-starter jars.

Comment: have you tried deleting the .m2 directory in you user home and run `mvn clean dependency:analyze`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this, but have no advanced,I find an other discuss which maybe helpful：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528928/spring-boot-core-dependencies-seen-as-unused-by-maven-dependency-plugin

Comment: Seem like spring-boot-starter tend to some job on runtime,which can not been scan by maven

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. Enventually [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528928/spring-boot-core-dependencies-seen-as-unused-by-maven-dependency-plugin) helped me, though for the sake of completeness this is what you can do:

Springboot does inspect the classpath and add dependencies on itself so you don't have to do it. For maven pedendency plugin this is intransparent and it seems that these dependencies are not used.

What I did to manage this:

1. Run: `mvn dependency:analyze`
   It will print out something like this:

```
    [WARNING] Unused declared dependencies found: 
    [WARNING] org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
```

2. Remove the dependency in your .pom file.
3. Run `mvn verify`
4. If the build fails due to missing dependencies, add this dependency as "usedDependency" to maven-dependency-plugin settings in .pom.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>analyze</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>analyze-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <ignoreNonCompile>true</ignoreNonCompile>
                        <failOnWarning>false</failOnWarning>
                        <outputXML>true</outputXML>
                        <usedDependencies>
                            <usedDependency>org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter</usedDependency>
                        </usedDependencies>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Repeat this for every warning found by maven dependency plugin.