# Use of spring-boot-starter jars triggers lint warnings

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, lint, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a springboot project that we got going quickly by using the various appropriate spring-boot-starter jars to bring in the appropriate transitive dependencies that we needed.  Now, as we get closer to production launch, we are adding code-quality and code-inspection tools to tighten up loose ends.  Some of these are tagging the starter jars as problematic, but I am finding inconsistent advice as to how to handle the problem.

Spring.io documentation fails to weigh in on this.  Starters are described here: [Spring Starters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.build-systems.starters), but it really just says they are used to "get going quickly" but does not indicate that they are intended for use in production.  The starters are not listed in the 'production ready' features (which focuses on Actuator).  The [Packaging for Production](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.packaging-for-production) makes no mention of starters.  From Spring documentation alone, you are encougaged to use the starters (to get going quickly), but are not told to, or told not to, use them in production.

If the spring project adds either [gradle-lint plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin), or uses [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/), use of the starters flags problems.  The starters include no code themselves, but they pull in useful transitive dependencies (by design), but that's contra-indicated by the lint plugins.  Related [incident here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528928/spring-boot-core-dependencies-seen-as-unused-by-maven-dependency-plugin)

> From [gradle-lint](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin/wiki/Unused-Dependency-Rule#convenience-when-dealing-with-empty-family-jars)  Generally, applications only use a subset of the libraries included in such families. The unnecessary dependencies included with the family both increase the footprint of the application itself. If the 'application' is actually itself a library, these unnecessary dependencies leak downstream to its users, increasing their footprint and potentially introducing breaking version conflict resolution problems.

Is the "right" answer to remove starter jars before going live?  Should starters be used in production?  I am sure there are plenty of projects that have gone to production with starters, and probably they have done so successfully.  But it looks to me like the authorities differ on what to do, so looking to reconcile them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is likely to be closed as it's opinion based. Speaking as a member of the Spring Boot team, the starters are absolutely intended for use in production. There's no point in something that gets you going quickly if it then creates more work later on. Some people dislike relying on transitive dependencies indirectly and believe that all dependencies that you require should be declared directly. I think the linting tools you've mentioned are enforcing this opinion. You can either configure the tool to quieten it or manually declare the starters' dependencies. I would do the former.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  This confirms that "the authorities are of different minds".  Spring.io says 'our starters are safe and can/should go to production'.  Linters, as a general rule, says 'don't use 'family libs'.   Choose Your Own Adventure  :)